# How to use TextBoxFor in helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've this code in razor page.

```
  @{ var countryCode = Model.CountryCode;}
                @if (countryCode.Equals("CA") || countryCode.Equals("US"))
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProvState, Model.Provinces)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProvState, Model.ProvState);
                }
```

I wrote this helper in LocatioHelper.cshtml

```
@helper RenderProvince(LocationModel model)
{
    var countryCode = model.CountryCode;
    if (countryCode.Equals("CA") || countryCode.Equals("US"))
    {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model.ProvState, model.Provinces)
    }
    else
    {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model.ProvState, model.ProvState);
    }
}
```

I've error that I must specify type for dropDownListFor and TextBoxFor explicitly, but on view I don't specify type.

How to move this into helper ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'helper'?

Comment: This is an issue using `@helper` methods in a shared (app_code) folder. If you put the helper method in the main view, you can use the `@Html.` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, you can pack your custom helper methods in a static class and declare your methods as simple extension methods on `HtmlHelper<T>.`

```
public static class CustomHelper
{
 public static MvcHtmlString YourCustomHelper<TModel, TValue> (
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression ---- )
    {
        //Write your custom logic here.
    }
}
```

You can import this class in your view and use this helper method using the usual syntax of `@Html.YourCustomHelper()`

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
In case you are using inline helper method keep the helper method in your View only where it is being used. Otherwise try creating an external html helper method as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You could write a normal HTML `helper` with `@Html.TextBoxFor` because that your view is strongly typed.
So you need something like:

```
public class HelperExtentions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DefaultRenderer<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, LocationModel model, SelectList selectList, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var countryCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CountryCode):"":model.CountryCode;
        var dtp = "";
        if (countryCode.Equals("CA") || countryCode.Equals("US"))
        {
            dtp = htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            dtp = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
        }
        sb.AppendFormat(dtp);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }

}
```

Then you can use :

```
@html.DefaultRenderer((m => m.ProvState, Models, newSelectList(/*some list data*/) ,new { @class = "form-control" }
```